# "Только и живёт, что предстоящим событием" - запятая категорически не нужна?

Tags: пунктуация

> Получение разрешения на этот брак, подготовка к пышным торжествам по
>   такому случаю займут почти два года. Бедный Карл всё это время
>   находится в страшном беспокойстве. Ему присланы её портреты, и он в
>   восторге описывает родителям свои первые впечатления о будущей
>   королеве. Он находит её восхитительной, он обнаруживает на портретах
>   блеск её ума… он только и живёт, что предстоящим событием!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, всё-таки категорически, это ведь неразложимое сочетание.

См. ответ № 259992 [здесь](http://gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20&start=600).

Comment: http://gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20&start=600

Comment: Спасибо, Люсенька! Там напоминалка: **Запятая не ставится перед словом *что* в выражении *только и... что,* за которым следует имя существительное или местоимение**. При глаголе - другой расклад.

Comment: Разве у нас глагол? Только и живёт что событием. Событие - существительное.

Comment: Я поняла, что речь о *живёт*. Которое якобы всё меняет.

Comment: Нет, "живёт" вместо многоточия, а ЗА выражением как раз существительное.

Answer (score 2):

Оборот в таком виде **звучит странно**, да и у Розенталя нет подобных примеров. У него  эти конструкции стандартны и ограничены в своих возможностях. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146

Можно предложить следующий вариант (самый близкий по теме): ...**он только и живёт что мыслями о ней.**

Comment: Есть-есть! *Только и денег что пятак в кармане* я не сама придумала!

Comment: Про пятак всё верно (это Розенталь), но обратите внимание, как строятся такие предложения:   Они или предметные, или глагольные, а у Вас ГЛАГОЛ + ПРЕДМЕТ. Правда же, сначала этот вариант просто не воспринимается на слух , а потом уже начинаешь разбираться с помощью Розенталя,  в чем там дело. А дело не в запятых, а в самой грамматике.

Comment: Угу. Спасибо. Вот ответ Справки, который всем угодил: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=282012 Но там есть дикий, имхо, пример: *А кто их знает, какие они будут?* И. Гончаров, Обрыв.

Comment: По Вашей ссылке пункт 9: Перед союзом что в выражении только и…что, за которым следует существительное или местоимение, запятая не ставится: Только и денег что пятак в кармане; Только и всего что рубашка на теле; Только и развлечений что кино раз в неделю; Только и свету что в окошке; Только и разговоров что о них двоих. Вы просто до конца не дочитали Розенталя.

Comment: Людмила,  эти замечания уместны для ваших школьников,  ко мне они точно не относятся. Если работаешь на этом сайте, то волей-неволей Розенталя не только дочитаешь до конца, но и  наизусть выучишь. И речь уже давно идет не о запятых, а о правильном построении этих конструкций,  вы просто немного отстали от темы.

Comment: Тогда бы Вы не сказали:  "У  Розенталя нет подобных примеров".

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что правильно так:
...он только и живёт предстоящим событием.

Или:
...он живёт только предстоящим событием.

Или:
...живет только одним — предстоящим событием.

*Однако уже сегодня Ашхабад живет предстоящим событием, что ощущается во всем...*

*Знаю, что вот уже несколько лет Поднебесная живёт предстоящим событием.*

*И целых три недели Москва работает, торгует, веселится, но, среди всех своих разнообразных дел, интересов и развлечений, втайне живет только одним — ожиданием знаменательного вечера двадцать седьмого декабря.*
И. А. Бунин. Благосклонное участие

Comment: Римуль, кто сминусовал - не знаю, не я; я наооборот; тут нельзя выкручиваться с перестройкой, это правило (подзабытое мной). Помню: ***только и денег что пятак в кармане*** (потому что существительное, а при последующем глаголе - иное).

Comment: Да, такое правило есть: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=620. Но меня почему-то изгрызли сомнения.

Comment: Правильно Вас сомнения изгрызли,   а не почему-то.  У предложения, как мне кажется, с грамматикой не все в порядке.

Comment: Во всех примерах - во всех правилах - перед "что" стоит существительное или местоимение в родительном падеже (обратите внимание). У нас же - глагол. Сюда вполне подошло бы предложение: Только и мыслей (разговоров) что о ее приезде. Во избежание спорности (по поводу запятой и, собственно, грамматики) я и подбирала свои предложения.